# WooCommerce OrderUtil Class Does Not Exist Despite Being Imported

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, wordpress-plugin-creation

Working with troubleshooting an issue on a Wordpress/WooCommerce site.

There is a plugin that uses the WooCommerce OrderUtil class and imports it before a handler class is declared.

```
use Automattic\WooCommerce\Utilities\OrderUtil;

class Order_Handler {

    public function set_checkout_order_meta() {

        if ( class_exists('OrderUtil') ) {

            // do some things here

        }

    }

}
```

For a reason that I cannot figure out, `class_exists('OrderUtil')`  returns `false`.

However `class_exists('Automattic\WooCommerce\Utilities\OrderUtil')` returns `true`.

I am stuck on how an imported class that exists is not available in  `Order_Handler`.

Note: I cannot update the code that checks for the `OrderUtil` class without breaking the plugin upgrade path.

Comment: In a plugin, `use Automattic\WooCommerce\Utilities\OrderUtil;`doesn"t work. Now, in WooCommerce High Performance Order Storage Upgrade Recipe Book documentation, you can [declare your extension (in)compatibility](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/High-Performance-Order-Storage-Upgrade-Recipe-Book#declaring-extension-incompatibility), so the class is accessible using the hook `before_woocommerce_init` and above woocommerce hooks… As a trick, you may want to use `get_option('woocommerce_custom_orders_table_enabled') === 'yes'` to check if HPOS is enabled or not...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sharing the answer found in a user-contributed note in the class_exists() docs on php.net

> If you are using aliasing to import namespaced classes, take care
> that class_exists will not work using the short, aliased class name -
> apparently whenever a class name is used as string, only the
> full-namespace version can be used
>
> use a\namespaced\classname as coolclass;
>
> class_exists( 'coolclass' ) => false

Solution is to use either of the following to check if the class exists

```
class_exists('Automattic\WooCommerce\Utilities\OrderUtil')
```

or

```
class_exists( OrderUtil::class)
```